# Show that if $p$ is prime and $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then $\frac{p-1}{2} \not\equiv \pm1 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Show that if $p$ is prime and $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then $\frac{p-1}{2} \not\equiv \pm1 \pmod p$.

Edit:

Could I say that a given is $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p \iff x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod p$ and then substitute in $x = \frac{p-1}{2}$ and show $(p-1) \not\equiv 1 \mod p$ giving me the final answer? If so how would I show this?

Comment: I can tell we will be talking about Legendre symbols soon in this Number Theory Class (I covered them last semester in Crypto I but I do not remember how to prove this). I spent 40+ min. attempting this one.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553314/prove-that-left-fracp-12-right-equiv-1n-mod-p-n-is-quad-no?rq=1

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502089/prove-that-ap-1-2-equiv-1-mod-p-and-ap-1-2-equiv-1-mod-p?rq=1

Look similar but are a little different.

Comment: The first proves more, but in particular it implies the result you are trying to prove.

Comment: We haven't covered quadratic residues yet in this class and I vaguely have an idea of what they are from last semester so I'm not sure I still could use that for this proof. 
Someone can explain a proof involving it though if they like and I'll try and understand.

Comment: I have posted an answer that does not mention QR explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $q=\frac{p-1}{2}$. Note that the numbers $q+1,q+2, \dots, 2q$ are congruent modulo $p$, in reverse order, to $-1,-2,\dots,-q$. It follows that
$$(p-1)!\equiv (-1)^q(q!)^2\pmod{p}.$$
But by Wilson's Theorem, we have $$(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}.$$
It follows that 
$$(q!)^2\equiv (-1)^{q-1}\pmod{p}.$$
If $p=4k+3$, then $q-1=2k$, which is even. Thus
$$(q!)^2\equiv 1\pmod{p}.$$
The result now follows.

Comment: It is not, I wrote "reverse order." So for example $\frac{p+1}{2}\equiv -\frac{p-1}{2}\pmod p$. Going to the end, we have $2a=p-1\equiv -1\pmod{p}$.  Do it for $p=13$. The numbers $7,8,\dots,12$ are congruent, in reverse order, to $-1,-2,\dots,-6$, or in order to $-6,-5,\dots,-1$.

Comment: My bad then. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Okay yeah it's easy to see that 2($\frac{p-1}{2}$) $\equiv$ -1 (mod p) and then like you said working along 1 by 1 getting -1, -2, ...
Then the rest follows. 
Alright thanks very much!