# The smallest number satisfying the Wilson congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Wilson's theorem says : if $p$ is a positive prime number, then $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.

The question is the following :

> When is it true that $a=p-1$ is the *smallest* positive number, such that $a! \equiv -1 \pmod p$?

That is, when is it true that for every $1\leq a < p-1$, we have $a!\not \equiv -1 \pmod p$?

This sequence has an OEIS entry [$A154554$](http://oeis.org/A154554), but the article is a stub thus far. The values read $2,3,5,13,17,31,\ldots$

One class of counterexamples is definitely called for. For a large class of primes, it seems to be true that $(\frac{p-1}{2})! \equiv -1 \pmod p$. The (increasing) list of primes which have this property read $7,11,19,43, 47, 67,\ldots$ , which has an OEIS entry [$A055939$](http://oeis.org/A055939) which is also listed [here](http://oeis.org/A055939/b055939.txt). It is interesting to note that every prime here is of the form $4k+3$ : that much can be proven easily.

More can be proven : see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553314/prove-that-left-fracp-12-right-equiv-1n-mod-p-n-is-quad-no?noredirect=1). In particular, $p = 4k+3$ is such that there are an odd number of quadratic non-residues modulo $p$ which are strictly smaller than $p/2$, if and only if $(\frac{p-1}{2})! \equiv -1 \pmod p$. So that is a classification of some counterexamples.

It is also interesting to note that it is not necessary that $a$ must have any "apparently immediate" multiplicative relationship with $p$. For example, $220! \equiv -1 \pmod{311}$ but I don't immediately see any kind of relation between these two quantities.

My basic question is : Do there exist necessary/sufficient conditions not invoking factorials (but perhaps invoking other quantities such as quadratic/polynomial residues, or primitive roots etc. : in short, not appearing like a very deliberate construction from the definition) regaring the membership of $p$ in $A154554$?

---

Speaking of primitive roots, we can also phrase the problem as follows : let $b$ be a primitive root modulo $p$. In that case, we know that for $n<p$,  for each $i \in \{2,3,...,n\}$ we have $i = b^{k_i}$ modulo $p$ for some $k_i$. Then the question comes down to : $n! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$ if and only if $\sum_{i=2}^n k_i \equiv \frac{p-1}{2} \mod{p-1}$ (which means that it's independent of the choice of $b$). So perhaps this question can be investigated using primitive roots as well, but that's just a suggestion and not really a planned attack on the question.

Comment: (Note : I am inactive for about 7-8 hours from now, I will reply to comments following this period. Thank you.)

Comment: A fact I remember is that Wilson's theorem is a deterministic test of probability (contrary to others that are probabilistic but unfortunately factorial is not good for time of calculation). However i don't feel this could be useful for your purpose. (Sorry for bad English). Regards. Greetings.

►It is proper of Number Theory that easy statement problems can be extremely difficult.

Comment: A remark maybe not impertinent: $\dfrac{p-1}{2}=\dfrac{p+1}{2}-1$ then if $\dfrac{p+1}{2}$ is prime (some analogue to Sophie Germain primes) then $$\left(\dfrac{p-1}{2}\right)!=\left(\dfrac{p+1}{2}-1\right)!\equiv-1\pmod{\dfrac{p+1}{2}}$$

Comment: @Piquito What you mean is that Wilson's theorem gives a necessary and sufficient condition when a number is prime, so can be used as a deterministic primality test and that this test has unfortunately no practical merit since there is no efficient way to calculate $n!\mod p$.

Comment: We could even use that for $p>4$ we have : $p$ is prime if and only if it does not divide $(p-1)!$ This seems even easier but still has no practical merit.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon $(1)$ I upvoted the question, but I do not expect a nice answer. There is no structure in the prime factors of $n!+1$. $(2)$ The problem for which primes $p$ we have $$(\frac{p-1}{2})!\equiv -1\mod p$$ seems to be a difficult partial problem. The given characterization is nice, but of no practical use. I wonder whether we can at least characterize those primes in a useful way.

Comment: @Peter: ►What I have said about Wilson's theorem is a known fact of criptography.

►Someone has downvoted first and I have upvoted for get the $0$ but inmediately another has downvoted to have again $-1$ and you have a second time get the $0$. What I want to say is that there are people spiked with bad conscience. Downvotes must be justified as a norm in MSE.

Comment: @Piquito Thanks for the talk about the downvotes, but it did not affect me , honestly. If I know my question is good, I expect the community to make it look good! Your remark is very interesting though : it seems to provide for a class of counterexamples as I see it. It seems that some journals on cryptography might have useful stuff to say about this problem : so maybe I will look up such journals for help.

Comment: @Peter: In all courtesy, I tell you that I feel that a G.H. Hardy would not agree with your "in a useful way".

Comment: @Piquito I think it should be clear that with "useful" , in this context , I mean a property that can be verified easier than just computing the congruence. Determining the parity of the number of non-residues would be more cumbersome.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon: Good luck! Cryptography is hard.

Comment: @Peter: I understand you. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito I agree : but it helps that I have the background! I'll attach new links here, and if you have additional thoughts, feel free to write an answer.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon: I have decided not answers anymore. Just comments. My goal here is not for mathematicians but help beginners. I am not at all interested in reputation points but I don't want either to have bad concience downvotes without justification.

Comment: @Piquito No problem : I will take your permission and convert some thoughts of yours into an answer when I get the chance to, later on. I'll make it community-wiki.

Comment: If $(a_{min})!\equiv -1 \bmod p$ and $k_i=(a_{min}+i), k_i\le p-1$ then $\prod k_i\equiv 1 \bmod p$. Thus, for any particular $k_n$, either its multiplicative inverse $\bmod p$ is found among the $k_i$ or its multiplicative inverse $\bmod p$ can be expressed as a product of two or more of the $k_i$. That's as far as I've got along this line of thought so far; maybe someone else can take it further.